# How to limit characters of the post title?

Tags: media, title

How do I limit the number of characters in a post title? I've seen it done in Yoast's Wordpress SEO plugin but I want to do something similar for the WP title.

I checked out a plugin called [Limit a post title to X characters](http://wordpress.org/plugins/limit-a-post-title-to-x-characters/) but it seems like it's been abandoned and it also breaks the Edit Media page since the media too has a title.

Comment: I'd like to get the character count in real time to help me craft the title (for tweetability, etc) as I type.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this :

```
add_action('publish_post', 'wpse_107434_title_max_char');
function wpse_107434_title_max_char() {
  global $post;
  $title = $post->post_title;
  if (strlen($title) >= 100 )
    wp_die( "the title must be 100 characters at most" );
  }
```

You can replace `strlen()` with `str_word_count()` if you want to set a word limit instead.

**EDIT:** ok with new details you added it seems you could add some jQuery to do the same (strlen)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm looking to get the character count in real time. I'll update my original question with that detail now.

Answer (score 2):

On a new post, the title is set in `<input type="text" name="post_title" size="30" value="" id="title" autocomplete="off">`.

Using a jQuery plugin like http://unwrongest.com/projects/limit/, you could write a WP plugin that targets the `post_title` and sets the limit right from the editor page.

You could also add a function in your theme's `functions.php` file instead of a plugin, depending on if you want to tie it in to the theme or the site.

This method makes it possible to keep original length titles if you decided to disable the plugin or change themes.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with this plugin, It's worked for me.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/limit-post-titles/

[image: publish post]